# browser acceptAlert() in webdriver io does not work in Chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, webdriver-io

In Chrome trying to click OK on the window popup, but browser accept Alert() does not work any more. It used to work. Now I am using web driver io version": "7.32.4".

[image]